# Any one given this role should be able to assign privieleges to other ORACLE COMMAND LINE

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlcommand

The Question given in Past Exam was

> you need to give academic role the ability to select from, insert
>   into and modify existing rows in Student table. **Anyone given this
>   Academic role should be able to Pass those privileges to other**. write
>   a query

```
  Create ROLE academic;       // I created the role 
  GRANT SELECT, INSERT, DELETE on student to academic; // Granted privileges
  GRANT academic to username; // passed it to user
```

Will the user have the privileges to pass it to others? If not, how to ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `WITH GRANT OPTION` clause at the end of the `GRANT` statement (the statement granting privileges on the table).

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9013.htm#i2062455  and scroll down a little bit to the **WITH GRANT OPTION** heading for documentation.